# Are there best practices for working with the Zurb Foundation grid in fluid mode?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Using Zurb Foundation 4 offers both small grids (for screens below 768px) and large grids as well as various visibility classes from .show/hide-for-small to .show/hide-for-xlarge.

Developing a fluid, non-fixed-width, layout, developers have the option to use both grids or show/hide dom elements depending on screen size. For certain constellations (e.g. switching from a 4-column to a three-column layout when screen size decreases), more complex measure may be needed. Examples could be structure conversion of the underlying dom elements or duplicating actual contents and showign/hiding the relevant structures based on screen size.

My question is what/if there are best practices for working with the Zurb Foundation grid in fluid mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by fluid mode in Zurb Foundation.

Regarding switching from a 4 to 3 column layout from large to mobile, I have always just put the visibility classes in the rows.

```
<div class="row hide-for-small">
  <div class="large-3 columns"></div>
  <div class="large-3 columns"></div>
  <div class="large-3 columns"></div>
  <div class="large-3 columns"></div>
</div>

<div class="row hide-for-medium-up">
  <div class="small-4 columns"></div>
  <div class="small-4 columns"></div>
  <div class="small-4 columns"></div>
</div>
```

Otherwise the normal behavior is stacking. You could go from 4 column to 3 column and stretch one of your columns 12 wide like so:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-3 small-4 columns">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="large-3 small-4 columns">Eius, ex vitae consequuntur nulla!</div>
  <div class="large-3 small-4 columns">Ipsam, assumenda ex non architecto.</div>
  <div class="large-3 small-12 columns">Tempore ipsa provident deserunt vel.</div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-3 small-12 columns">Tempore ipsa provident deserunt vel.</div>
  <div class="large-3 small-4 columns">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="large-3 small-4 columns">Eius, ex vitae consequuntur nulla!</div>
  <div class="large-3 small-4 columns">Ipsam, assumenda ex non architecto.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @JJJ: By "fluid" I meant a full-width layout, not fixed to n px as the Zurb default one. This is already helpful- you're suggesting stacking and duplicating content as measures. I'm wondering if/what other techniques there are.

Comment: if you are using F4 you can also use sass mixins and media queries directly on your clases and ids.